# Spark DataFrame Get Difference between values of two rows

Tags: apache-spark

I have calculated the average temperature for two cities grouped by seasons, but I'm having trouble in with getting the difference between the avg(TemperatureF) for City A vs City B.  Here is an example of what my Spark Scala DataFrame looks like:

| City | Season | avg(TemperatureF) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Fall | 52 |
| A | Spring | 50 |
| A | Summer | 72 |
| A | Winter | 25 |
| B | Fall | 49 |
| B | Spring | 44 |
| B | Summer | 69 |
| B | Winter | 22 |

Answer (score 1):

You may use the pivot function as follows:

```
df.groupBy('Season').pivot('City').agg(f.first('avg')) \
  .withColumn('diff', f.expr('A - B')) \
  .show()

+------+---+---+----+
|Season|  A|  B|diff|
+------+---+---+----+
|Spring| 50| 44| 6.0|
|Summer| 72| 69| 3.0|
|  Fall| 52| 49| 3.0|
|Winter| 25| 22| 3.0|
+------+---+---+----+
```